# is it possible to createElement through php

Tags: php, javascript, html

is it possible to create Element or change attribute or innerHTML of a html element on the webpage like javascript does?

```
document.createElement("label");
```

any how is it possible with php..

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is somewhat ambiguous. PHP outputs markup/code that the client renders/runs. Unless you want to build markup on the server using some kind of server-side DOM methods to then output to the client as HTML, you could just do `<script><?php echo 'document.createElement("label");';?></script>` and it would run on the client. *Manipulating* the browser directly with actual PHP code, no you can't do that.

Comment: no is it possible without javascript and only php?

Comment: @KrishnaSarswat - No, not without reloading the page and having it resend a new HTML document. In a way, this is what a [postback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback) does.

Comment: @Jared :) you are overthinking this. Krishna hasn't yet figured out the relationship between PHP and HTML  or JS and HTML ... there is a learning curve.

Comment: @KrishnaSarswat, Why not just do a simple `require_once('initall.php')` and be done with it?

Comment: See the [`dateType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) parameter. You can return an HTML fragment from your calling page instead of a string to parse into DOM elements. So sure, you can do that, but it doesn't involve PHP itself "controlling" the DOM, you're just providing markup back as a response to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that PHP is server side processing, and Javascript is Client Side processing.

PHP can directly manipulate HTML(and JavaScript) before it is sent to the client.

Comment: acutally i want to manipulate html data without using js, is it possible?

Comment: @KrishnaSarswat, manipulate how?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: of course, what does your php code do now? :)

Comment: for example, if i want to createElement on basis of a html element id, so is it possible to get the id attribute of that element through php?

Comment: I'll add one more thing. You can also edit HTML directly without PHP.

Comment: @DmitryB actually a client of me asked me to do a shopping cart process, without using javascript and he wanted that for example the pizza's sauce & salad must come under the main table column of that pizza in cart

Comment: Sometimes clients need to be told NO! :) Tell the client to order pizza by phone.

Comment: @KrishnaSarswat - It's odd that a client (paying?) would request you avoid a particular technique such as using Javascript. If they are not a developer, inquire why; they may have been bit by it in the past, and if you want to forge ahead with Javascript anyway, you need to understand what the hangup is and why.

Answer (score 0):

Simply: no.

PHP is a server side language, while JavaScript is run client side. PHP can be used to change the html code of a page while the page is loading, but not after the page has loaded like JavaScript can.

Answer (score 0):

No.  At least, not the way JavaScript does.

PHP runs server-side, not client-side.  This means that PHP does all of its' work before the page is even sent to the browser.  The browser does not run PHP code.

Now, you can manipulate the DOM using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), but again, this is before the page is sent to the browser in the first place.

Comment: can i function all DOM functions using php, even it does before the page load..

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the DOM before the page loads, but I don't think that is what you are asking for.  It is completely unclear what you are trying to do.  Don't be so vague and explain fully what you are trying to accomplish, by editing your original question.

Comment: i've edited the question and added the js script which i want to do using php

Answer (score 0):

No.

PHP = server-side
JS = client-side

For the most part, they DO NOT MIX.

Exceptions: PHP can output JavaScript to the browser. JavaScript can invoke PHP via AJAX.

Comment: Just adding a comment to clarify for Krishna that JavaScript isn't really invoking PHP directly with AJAX.  All AJAX is, is another call to the server... no different if you were to put that URL in the address bar.  The browser doesn't know or care that PHP is running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do AJAX posts without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php to print out javascript to create an element.